# How can you distribute an app for testing if Apple reject it from TestFlight?

Tags: ios

I have an app I wish to distribute to people for testing and evaluation. 
The app is not intended for release to the app store. I tried to add it to TestFlight anyway but during TestFlight review Apple rejected it as its breaking an app store submission rule (why do they even need to bother reviewing TestFlight submissions when its not even been submitted to the app store yet?).

The latest versions of iTunes no longer has the ability to install an .ipa so that method of installation is no longer available.

Diawi is useful, but the lifetime that links on there are active is just a few days.

Is there some other easy alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fabric to distribute test builds. You can find more info [here](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/beta-walkthrough.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Fabric, Just take the testers emails and send them invitations.

refer to Fabric documentation for further info https://fabric.io/onboard

it's very simple and way faster then Testflight

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that Fabric distribution requires you to put each device UUID into your distribution profile?